# how connect to models.py? Some Django views.py are not working

Tags: python, django

i am new with django/python. i have project in Django for calculate paper price.

```
class Calculate(View):
def get(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('signIn')

    user = request.user
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    p_info_list = []
    u_info = UserInfo(user)
    user_in_projects = []
    k_info_list = []


    for p in projects:
        tasks = p.task_set.all()
        print(f"Project: {p.name}, Tasks: {tasks}")
        print(f"p object: {p}")
        for task in tasks:
            print(f"Task object: {task_object}")  # Check the value before object creation

        if p.owner == user or user.id in p.get_members():
            p_info = ProjectInfo(p)
            u_info.analyze_project(p)
            p_info_list.append(p_info)
            user_in_projects.append(UserInProject(user, p))
            print(f"P Info object: {p_info}")

        for task in p.task_set.all():
            print(f"Task object: {task}")  # Print the entire task object
            print(f"Task: {task.name}, tipe_kertas: {task.tipe_kertas}")

            k_info_obj = KalkulatorInfo(task)  # Or pass relevant data containing paper properties
            print(f"KalkulatorInfo object: {k_info_obj}")
            price = k_info_obj.calculate_price(task.tipe_kertas, task.gramatur_kertas, task.ukuran_kertas)
            k_info_obj.price = price  # Assuming KalkulatorInfo has a price attribute
            k_info_list.append(k_info_obj)
```

why `task_object`  not working when i debugging from `print()`

the entire `for task in p.task_set.all()` are not working.

here is the `models.py`:

```
class KalkulatorInfo:
def __init__(self, task_object):
    self.tipe_kertas = task_object.tipe_kertas  # Assuming task object has these attributes
    self.gramatur_kertas = task_object.gramatur_kertas
    self.ukuran_kertas = task_object.ukuran_kertas
    self.price = self.calculate_price()  # Calculate price upon initialization

def calculate_price(self):
    price_dict = {
        ("ap", "80", "a4"): 10000,
        ("bp", "100", "a4"): 12000,
        # ... other combinations and prices
    }
    print(f"this is price dict: {price_dict}")
```

thank you for helping. i apriciate it

Comment: `for task in tasks` and then `print(f"Task object: {task_object}")` you probably meant to write `task` instead of `task_object` there since there's no such variable.

Comment: right. I think everything is fine. is there anything i missed?